# Export JS fuction to use in other JS not working

Tags: javascript, function, methods, import, export

This is my the my js:

```js
//aca Z
 var Z = (function () {
    var i = "#z-overlay {filter: alpha(opacity=50);opacity:0.5;display:inline-block;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color: #000;z-index: 1001;}";
    var u =
        "#z-container {border:1px;float:left; overflow: visible; position: absolute;padding: 0px; display: inline-block; top:5%; left:34%; margin: 0 auto;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;border-radius:5px;background-color: #FAFAFA; border:1px solid #FAFAFA;border-top-color:#EDEDED;behavior: url(js/PIE.htc);z-index: 1002;}";
    var h = "#z-data {height: 100%; outline: 0px; width: 100%; overflow: visible;display: inline-block;border:1px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;border-radius:5px;}";
    var t = "#reset{*, *:before, *:after {display: inline-block;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}}";
    var l = "#z_hppm_iframe {background-color: #FAFAFA;vertical-align:bottom;z-index:9999;display:block;padding:0px;margin: 0px; border:0px solid #DDD;}";
    var e = "requestPage";
    var d;
    var s;
    var c, o;
    var b;
    var n;
    var w = ["tenantId", "id", "token", "signature", "key", "style", "submitEnabled", "url"];
    var j = ["creditCardNumber", "cardSecurityCode", "creditCardExpirationYear", "creditCardExpirationMonth", "bankAccountNumber", "bankAccountName", "ipAddress", "achBankAccountNumber", "achBankABACode"];
    var r = false;
    var m = {};
    var f = null;
    var v = null;
    function a(x) {
        return x && typeof x === "function";
    }
    function p(x) {
        var y = {};
        for (var z in x) {
            if (x.hasOwnProperty(z)) {
                y[z] = x[z];
            }
        }
        return y;
    }
    function k() {
        if (s) {
            s();
        }
    }
    function g() {
        s = null;
    }
    function q(x) {
        if (x.currentStyle) {
            return x.currentStyle.display != "none";
        } else {
            if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
                return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue("display") != "none";
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    ZXD.receiveMessage(function (y) {
        try {
            var x = y.data;
            ZLOG.debug("Received message[O]: payload=" + x);
            x = JSON.parse(x);
            if (x.success) {
                if (a(m.init)) {
                    m.init(x);
                }
            } else {
                if (x.success == false) {
                    Z.deactivateOverlay("z-overlay");
                    Z.deactivateOverlay("z-container");
                    if (m.init) {
                        m.init(x);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (x.action == "close") {
                        Z.deactivateOverlay("z-overlay");
                        Z.deactivateOverlay("z-container");
                    } else {
                        if (x.action == "resize") {
                            Z.receive(x);
                        } else {
                            if (x.action == "allowScroll") {
                                Z.allowScroll(x);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (x.action === "validate" && a(m.validate)) {
                m.validate(x);
            } else {
                if (x.action == "customizeErrorMessage" && a(m.customizeErrorMessage)) {
                    m.customizeErrorMessage(x.key, x.code, x.message, x.rawGatewayInfo);
                } else {
                    if (x.action && a(m[x.action])) {
                        m[x.action](x);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (z) {
            return;
        }
    });
    return {
        validateRequiredParams: function (z) {
            var x = w.length;
            for (index = 0; index < x; index++) {
                if (!z.hasOwnProperty(w[index])) {
                    if (w[index] == "submitEnabled" && z.style.toLowerCase() == "overlay") {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        var y = "Param with key [" + w[index] + "] is required.";
                        alert(y);
                        if (!Z.isIE()) {
                            console.log(y);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        },
        isIE: function () {
            var z = window.navigator.userAgent;
            var y = z.indexOf("MSIE ");
            var x = z.indexOf("Trident/");
            if (y > 0) {
                return true;
            }
            if (x > 0) {
                var A = z.indexOf("rv:");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
        validatePCIParams: function (A) {
            var x = j.length;
            for (index = 0; index < x; index++) {
                if (j[index] == "achBankAccountNumber" || j[index] == "achBankABACode") {
                    return true;
                }
                var y = "field_" + j[index];
                if (A.hasOwnProperty(y)) {
                    if (0 < A[y].trim().length && A[y].trim().length < 300) {
                        var z = "Field [" + y + "] for Credit Card payment method type should be encrypted for pre-population";
                        alert(z);
                        if (!Z.isIE()) {
                            console.log(z);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        },
        init: function (C, D) {
            c = "?method=requestPage&host=" + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href) + "&";
            c = c + "fromHostedPage=true&";
            var B = Z.validateRequiredParams(C);
            if (!B) {
                return false;
            }
            B = Z.validatePCIParams(C);
            if (!B) {
                return false;
            }
            var A = JSON.stringify(C, function (F, G) {
                if (F != "") {
                    if ("key" == F) {
                        b = G;
                    } else {
                        if ("url" == F) {
                            var E = /^https:\/\/([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+zuora\.com\/.+$/;
                            ZLOG.info("HPM integration[O]: url=" + G);
                            if (!E.test(G)) {
                                ZLOG.warn("HPM integration[O]: None-official zuora HPM integration url is detected: " + G);
                            }
                            d = G;
                        } else {
                            c = c + F + "=" + encodeURIComponent(G) + "&";
                        }
                    }
                }
                return G;
            });
            n = JSON.parse(A);
            m.init = D;
            var x = j.length;
            if (C) {
                for (var z = 0; z < x; z++) {
                    var y = "field_" + j[z];
                    if (C.hasOwnProperty(y)) {
                        C[y] = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        },
        prepopulate: function (z) {
            if (threedRedirected) {
                return;
            }
            var A = Z.createIframeURL();
            if (A == document.getElementById(ifrmId).src || (document.getElementById(ifrmId).src.indexOf(A) >= 0 && n.hasOwnProperty("customizeErrorRequired") && n.customizeErrorRequired == "true")) {
                var x = JSON.stringify(z, function (B, D) {
                    if (B != "") {
                        var C = "setField(" + B + ":" + D + ")";
                        Z.post(ifrmId, C);
                    }
                    return D;
                });
                var y = "setField(key:" + b + ")";
                Z.post(ifrmId, y);
                Z.post(ifrmId, "setField(style:" + n.style + ")");
                if (n.hasOwnProperty("customizeErrorRequired") && n.customizeErrorRequired == "true") {
                    Z.post(ifrmId, "customizeErrorRequired");
                    n.customizeErrorRequired = "false";
                }
            }
        },
        contains: function (x, z) {
            for (var y = 0; y < x.length; y++) {
                if (x[y] === z) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        },
        renderWithErrorHandler: function (B, D, C, y, z, x, A) {
            B.customizeErrorRequired = "true";
            Z.render(B, D, C, z, x);
            Z.customizeErrorHandler(y);
            Z.removeCoverHandler(A);
        },
        runAfterRender: function (x) {
            s = x;
        },


          render: function (C, B, H, A, I) {
            console.log('testRender');
            if (A != null && A != undefined) {
                f = A;
            }
            if (I != null && I != undefined) {
                v = I;
            }
            f = Number(f);
            v = Number(v);
            f = isNaN(f) ? 0 : f;
            v = isNaN(v) ? 0 : v;
            var F = j.length;
            threedRedirected = false;
            if (B && B.creditCardCountry && (B.creditCardCountry === "USA" || B.creditCardCountry === "CAN")) {
                B.creditCardState = B.creditCardState || " ";
            }
            if (B) {
                for (index = 0; index < F; index++) {
                    var D = "field_" + j[index];
                    if (B.hasOwnProperty(j[index])) {
                        C[D] = B[j[index]];
                    }
                }
            }
            var J = Z.init(C, H);
            if (!J) {
                return;
            }
            if (B) {
                var F = Object.keys(B).length;
                o = p(B);
                for (index = 0; index < F; index++) {
                    var z = Object.keys(B)[index];
                    if (Z.contains(j, z)) {
                        delete o[z];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                o = null;
            }
            var y = document.getElementById("zuora_payment");
            if (typeof y == "undefined" || !y) {
                return { error: "invalid_request", error_description: "The container you specified does not exist" };
            }
            y.innerHTML = "";
            Z.cleanUp(y, "z-overlay");
            Z.cleanUp(y, "z-container");
            if (n.style == "inline") {
                Z.addInlineStyles();
                Z.createIframe(y);
                return;
            }
            if (n.style == "overlay") {
                Z.addOverlayStyles();
                var x = Z.generateDiv("z-overlay", "z-overlay");
                y.appendChild(x);
                var E = Z.generateDiv("z-container", "z-container");
                y.appendChild(E);
                var G = Z.generateDiv("z-data", "z-data");
                G.tabindex = "-1";
                E.appendChild(G);
                Z.createIframe(document.getElementById("z-data"));
                Z.activateOverlay("z-overlay");
            }
        },
        

        cleanUp: function (y, x) {
            var z = document.getElementById(x);
            if (z != null) {
                y.removeChild(z);
            }
        },

        
        activateOverlay: function (y) {
            try {
                document.getElementById(y).style.display = "inline";
            } catch (x) {}
        },
        deactivateOverlay: function (y) {
            try {
                document.getElementById(y).style.display = "none";
            } catch (x) {}
        },
        generateDiv: function (A, y, x) {
            var z = document.createElement("div");
            z.id = A;
            z.className = y;
            z.border = "0";
            if (z.addEventListener) {
                z.addEventListener("click", x, false);
            } else {
                z.attachEvent("click", x);
            }
            return z;
        },
        addOverlayStyles: function () {
            var B = document.createElement("style");
            B.type = "text/css";
            var y = document.createTextNode(i);
            var C = document.createTextNode(u);
            var x = document.createTextNode(h);
            var A = document.createTextNode(l);
            var z = document.createTextNode(t);
            if (B.styleSheet) {
                B.styleSheet.cssText = y.nodeValue + " " + C.nodeValue + " " + x.nodeValue + " " + z.nodeValue + " " + A.nodeValue;
            } else {
                B.appendChild(y);
                B.appendChild(C);
                B.appendChild(x);
                B.appendChild(A);
                B.appendChild(z);
            }
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(B);
        },
        addInlineStyles: function () {
            var y = document.createElement("style");
            y.type = "text/css";
            var x = document.createTextNode(l);
            if (y.styleSheet) {
                y.styleSheet.cssText = x.nodeValue;
            } else {
                y.appendChild(x);
            }
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(y);
        },
        createIframe: function (y) {
            var A = Z.createIframeURL();
            var z = document.createElement("iframe");
            z.setAttribute("src", A);
            z.setAttribute("id", ifrmId);
            z.setAttribute("overflow", "visible");
            z.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
            z.setAttribute("frameBorder", "0");
            z.setAttribute("allowtransparency", "true");
            z.setAttribute("class", "z_hppm_iframe");
            z.setAttribute("width", "100%");
            z.setAttribute("height", "0");
            var x = false;
            z.addEventListener(
                "load",
                function () {
                    Z.prepopulate(o);
                    k();
                    g();
                    function B() {
                        if (q(y)) {
                            Z.post(ifrmId, "resize");
                            if (a(m.onloadCallback)) {
                                m.onloadCallback();
                            }
                        } else {
                            window.requestAnimationFrame(B);
                        }
                    }
                    if (!x) {
                        window.requestAnimationFrame(B);
                        x = true;
                    }
                    return false;
                },
                false
            );
            if (typeof options != "undefined") {
                if (typeof options.vertical != "undefined" && options.vertical) {
                    z.style.width = "100%";
                    z.style.height = "100%";
                }
            }
            y.appendChild(z);
        },
        createIframeURL: function () {
            var x = d;
            return x.concat(c).concat("zlog_level=" + ZLOG.getLevel());
        },
        post: function (A, z) {
            var x = document.getElementById(A);
            var y = encodeURIComponent(document.location.href);
            var B = x.src;
            if (B.indexOf(y) <= -1) {
                x.src = B + "#" + y;
            }
            ZXD.postMessage(z, B, x.contentWindow);
            return false;
        },
        allowScroll: function (y) {
            if (ifrmId) {
                var x = document.getElementById(ifrmId);
                if (x) {
                    x.setAttribute("scrolling", "yes");
                    threedRedirected = true;
                }
            }
        },
        receive: function (x) {
            ZFB.resizeCaller(ifrmId, x.action, x.height, x.width, f, v);
        },
        validate: function (z) {
            if (z == null || z == undefined) {
                Z.closeWindow();
                var y = "Validate function required.";
                alert(y);
                if (!Z.isIE()) {
                    console.log(y);
                }
                return false;
            }
            m.validate = z;
            var x = "validate";
            Z.post(ifrmId, x);
        },
        customizeErrorHandler: function (y) {
            if (y == null || y == undefined) {
                Z.closeWindow();
                var x = "Customized error message function required.";
                alert(x);
                if (!Z.isIE()) {
                    console.log(x);
                }
                return false;
            }
            m.customizeErrorMessage = y;
        },
        removeCoverHandler: function (x) {
            if (x == null || x == undefined) {
                return false;
            }
            m.removeCover = x;
        },
        sendErrorMessageToHpm: function (A, z) {
            var y = { action: "customizeErrorMessage", key: A, message: z };
            var x = JSON.stringify(y);
            Z.post(ifrmId, x);
        },
        closeWindow: function () {
            Z.deactivateOverlay("z-overlay");
            Z.deactivateOverlay("z-container");
        },
        submit: function () {
            var x = document.getElementById(ifrmId).src + "#" + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href);
            document.getElementById(ifrmId).src = x;
            ZXD.postMessage("postPage", x, document.getElementById(ifrmId).contentWindow);
            return true;
        },
        responseHandler: function (x) {
            var y = x.redirectUrl;
            if (x.success) {
                var z = y + "?refId=" + x.refId + "&success=" + x.success + "&signature=" + x.signature + "&token=" + x.token;
                window.location.replace(z);
            } else {
                var z = y + "?errorCode=" + x.errorCode + "&errorMessage=" + x.errorMessage + "&success=" + x.success + "&signature=" + x.signature + "&token=" + x.token;
                window.location.replace(z);
            }
        },
        setEventHandler: function (x, y) {
            if (x && y) {
                m[x] = y;
            }
        },
        setAgreement: function (A, B, z, y) {
            if (!Z.validateAgreement(A, B, z)) {
                return false;
            }
            var x = "mitConsentAgreementSrc";
            Z.setFieldValue(x, A);
            x = "mitCredentialProfileType";
            Z.setFieldValue(x, B);
            x = "agreementSupportedBrands";
            Z.setFieldValue(x, z);
            x = "mitConsentAgreementRef";
            Z.setFieldValue(x, y);
            return true;
        },
        setFieldValue: function (x, z) {
            var y = "setField(" + x + ":" + z + ")";
            Z.post(ifrmId, y);
        },
        validateAgreement: function (y, z, x) {
            if (Z.isEmpty(y) && Z.isEmpty(z) && Z.isEmpty(x)) {
                return true;
            }
            if (Z.isEmpty(y)) {
                Z.alertRequired("mitConsentAgreementSrc");
                return false;
            }
            if (Z.isEmpty(z)) {
                Z.alertRequired("mitProfileType");
                return false;
            }
            if (Z.isEmpty(x)) {
                Z.alertRequired("agreementSupportedBrands");
                return false;
            }
            if (y != "External") {
                Z.alertIllegal("mitConsentAgreementSrc");
                return false;
            }
            if (z != "Recurring" && z != "Unscheduled") {
                Z.alertIllegal("mitProfileType");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        },
        isEmpty: function (x) {
            return !x || 0 === x.length;
        },
        alertRequired: function (y) {
            var x = "Param mitConsentAgreementSrc, mitProfileType and agreementSupportedBrands for Z.setAgreement should be all empty or not empty. Param " + y + " is empty.";
            alert(x);
        },
        alertIllegal: function (y) {
            var x = "Param " + y + " for Z.setAgreement is illegal.";
            alert(x);
        },
    };
})();
export {Z};
```

I'm trying to export the render function to use in other js that is in the same folder but is not working.
I tried: put export at the beginning of the function (photo) and I also tried

export {render} from './zouralibrary';
but in thiscase is thorow me:  Unexpected compilation error: 'default' is not exported by zouralibrary.js, imported by paymentIframeTest.js (3:7)

Comment: how are you exporting the render and how are you importing it?
Please, show all relevant code

Comment: It looks like your `render` is a property of an object. You need to either export the parent object as default, or `export const render = parentObject.render`;

Comment: I just updated the post, I put the rest of the code. Can you take a look ?

Comment: Well, your code is exporting `{Z}`... where is the code where you import `{Z}` ?  The function itself is not useful here in this context of your question, since our issue is import and export. And is Z inside zouralibrary.js ?